# Android: TableLayout programmatically fill up the whole screen with equal cells

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

Trying to do a dynamic TableLayout in Android.

In my layout there is only this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_table"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
</TableLayout>
```

I want to dynamically add rows (and columns) to this table, because at compile time it is unknown how many cells will I need to display.

What is known for sure however, that the whole table **must** fit to the screen (fit and stretch actually).

I created a layout for the rows too (for now with 2 fixed cells):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Rate User1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Rate User2"
        />

</TableRow>
```

In the activity's onCreate function I'm inflating 3 rows and I expect them to lay all over the screen:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_table);

    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f /*0.33f*/);

    TableRow tableRow1 = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_stream_row, tableLayout, false);
    tableRow1.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

    TableRow tableRow2 = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_stream_row, tableLayout, false);
    tableRow2.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

    TableRow tableRow3 = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_stream_row, tableLayout, false);
    tableRow3.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

    //tableLayout.setWeightSum(1f);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow1);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow2);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow3);
}
```

But for now the row heights matches their content instead of stretching to the whole screen:

[image]

If I comment out the *addView*s, and put 3 TableRows into the main layout, it looks like as I want:

[image]

**So the question is how can I achieve my desired result (2nd image), if putting rows directly into the layout file is not an option?**

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to change the LayoutParams of TableRow:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f);
```

to LayoutParams of TableLayout:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
```

After this change the layout is stretching to the whole screen.